# Sybase - How To Output Variable Contents To File

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-iq

I'm writing a procedure in Sybase using Interactive SQL.  The proc contains several `SELECT` statements that store the results in variables, eg

```
DROP VARIABLE IF EXISTS @totalRows;
CREATE VARIABLE @totalRows LONG VARCHAR;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @totalRows FROM <MyTable>;
```

I'd like to be able to output the results of this query to a CSV file but I get an error when trying to run the following statement

```
DROP VARIABLE IF EXISTS @totalRows;
CREATE VARIABLE @totalRows LONG VARCHAR;
SELECT COUNT(*)  INTO @totalRows FROM <MyTable>;
OUTPUT TO 'C:\\temp\\TEST.CSV' FORMAT ASCII DELIMITED BY ';' QUOTE '' WITH COLUMN NAMES;
```

The error reads

```
Could not execute statement.  
Syntax error near 'OUTPUT' on line 4.  
SQLCODE=-131, ODBC 3 State="42000".  
Line 1, column 1
```

If I remove the `OUTPUT TO` section of the query it runs fine.  Is it possible in Sybase to write the contents of a variable to an external file in this manner?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like, 'OUTPUT' clause is not supported by Sybase.
As a workaround, you may run this query using some text-based tool (like sqlite) and redirect (>) the output into file, if you happen to use linux box at your client end. 
Or, you may add ODBC data source (which will require sybase ODBC-driver) corresponding to your DB in Windows and use MS Excel embedded tool Microsoft Query (Data -> From other sources -> From Microsoft Query) in order to export your query result directly into excel datasheet, which you may save as CSV.

Answer (score 0):

OUTPUT TO is a dbisql command, i.e. a directive for the dbisql client utility. It is not a SQL statement. If you try to execute this with anything other than dbisql, you'll get an error. 
BTW -- I believe the OUTPUT clause must follow the semicolon that terminates the SELECT stmt, i.e. not have a line break in between.

Answer (score 0):

Need add select variable before output statement

```
DROP VARIABLE IF EXISTS @totalRows;
CREATE VARIABLE @totalRows LONG VARCHAR;
SELECT COUNT(*)  INTO @totalRows FROM <MyTable>;
SELECT @totalRows; --select variable before output
OUTPUT TO 'C:\\temp\\TEST.CSV' FORMAT ASCII DELIMITED BY ';' QUOTE '' WITH COLUMN NAMES;
```